# Quickly find joint pairs in a python list of numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, set

I have a list of `numpy` arrays and want to get the indices of the joint pairs. Basically, if I have the following list of lists:

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 9], [5, 6], [9]]
```

I want the following:

```
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Here's what I have so far, but it's slow:

```
out = out
for i, item in enumerate(lst):
    for j in range(i+1, len(lst)):
        if not set(item).isdisjoint(lst[j]):
            out.append([i, j])
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: in your example the only disjoint pair is `[1,2] and [0,3]` is that what you expect as an answer?

Comment: Oops, sorry my bad. I meant joint. Updated the question @Landar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = [[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 9], [5, 6], [9]]
lst_set = [set(e) for e in lst]

print([[x, y] for x, y in combinations(range(len(lst)), 2) if not lst_set[x].isdisjoint(lst_set[y])])
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3]]
```